# How to tell which colorscheme a Vim session currently uses

Tags: vim, configuration, syntax-highlighting

You can *set* the Vim color scheme by issuing

```
:colorscheme SCHEME_NAME
```

but, oddly enough, you can't get the currently used scheme by issuing

```
:colorscheme
```

as this results in "`E471: Argument required`". I also don't see the color scheme listed in the output of `:set`.

So how do you go about figuring out the current color scheme in use (other than manually switching the themes until you recognize it)?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

There's no guaranteed way (as a colour scheme is essentially a load of vim commands that are sourced).  However, by convention there should be a variable `g:colors_name` that is set to the name of the colour scheme.

Therefore, try this:

```
echo g:colors_name
```

If you get E121, it's either a poorly made colour scheme or it's the default one.

A shinier way of doing this is (for recent versions of vim):

```
function! ShowColourSchemeName()
    try
        echo g:colors_name
    catch /^Vim:E121/
        echo "default"
    endtry
endfunction
```

Then do:

```
:call ShowColourSchemeName()
```

If it says "default", do `:colorscheme default` and see if the colours change.  If they do, you're using a malformed colour scheme and there's not a lot you can do about it other than manually switching themes until you recognise it.

The variable `g:colors_name` is documented [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:colorscheme):

```
:help colorscheme
```

Comment: The first time this function is run VIM drops and error. However, when I loaded :colorscheme default, it worked well because there IS colors/default.vim colorscheme.

Comment: how to do the same for neovim?

Comment: This error does not seem to be catchable. Vim just responds with an error and does not echo 'default'

Answer (score 45):

Best option is to use `:colo` or `:colorscheme` in current vim and the actual colorscheme text is shown. Please see,

```
:help colorscheme
```

for more details.

Comment: It doesn't work to me. It says `default`. And the color scheme I get when I execute `:colo default` it's another one.

Answer (score 14):

A one-line version of DrAl's answer:

```
let current_scheme = get(g:, 'colors_name', 'default')
```

The `get()` function will fall back to `'default'` if the variable has not yet been set.