# Vim, show current colorscheme before prompting

Tags: vim

I found a post where one asks how to [show the current `colorscheme`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419624/how-to-tell-which-colorscheme-a-vim-session-currently-uses). I'd like to combine this with the prompt. That is, separately, `:colorscheme>CR>` and `:colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>` work, as showing and prompting for `colorscheme` respectively. I'm not sure how to combine these into one command. Here are my attempts,

```
nnoremap <leader>c :echo g:colors_name \n<CR>
function! Colors()
    :colorscheme<cr>
    :colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>c :exec Colors()
nnoremap <leader>c :colorscheme<cr>:colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
nnoremap <leader>c :echo g:colors_name<cr><bar>:colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
```

Separately, these two work:

```
nnoremap <leader>s :colorscheme<CR>
nnoremap <leader>c :colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
```

(By the way, I use `set wildcharm=<C-z>` and `set wildmenu wildmode=list:full`.)

Comment: What is `<C-z><S-Tab> ` supposed to do?

Comment: @merlin2011, simply, it makes the `wildmenu`/`wildmode` kick in. `wildcharm` assigns `<C-z>` to `<Tab>` for including in macros. So `<C-z>` makes the tab completion options appear, but also enters the first item in the tab completion list in the command line. Then, `<S-Tab>` reverses that, so that tab completion list still appears, but you can type from where you left off to limit completion candidates.

Comment: @merlin2011 Oh, I just realized, the behavior of `Tab` may have some dependence on what I have `wildmenu` and `wildmode` are set to (how many items in `wildmode`, as a comma separated list?). I will add these.

Comment: Well, it's easy enough to use `,c<RET>` to see the colorscheme. Now I have similar for `,a` is `AirlineTheme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can combine them into one command. I wrote a function to find all color schemes print the current and prompt you for a list. The current color scheme name is contained in `g:colors_name`.

```
function! PromptList(prompt, list)
    let l:copy = copy(a:list)
    for i in range(len(l:copy))
        let l:copy[i] = (i + 1) . '. ' . l:copy[i]
    endfor
    let l:ret = inputlist([a:prompt] + l:copy)
    if l:ret > 0 && l:ret < len(a:list)
        return a:list[l:ret - 1]
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction

function! ChangeColorscheme()
    " Get a sorted list with the available color schemes.
    let l:list = sort(map(
                \ split(globpath(&runtimepath, 'colors/*.vim'), '\n'),
                \ 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")'))

    let l:prompt = 'Current color scheme is ' . g:colors_name
    let l:color = PromptList(l:prompt, l:list)
    if l:color != ''
        exec 'colorscheme' l:color
    endif
endfunction
```

To use it type `:call ChangeColorscheme()`